# Выставление частоты экрана в Linux Mandriva

Tags: mandriva, linux

Подскажите, пожалуйста! Как на linux mandriva поставить в ноутбуке разрешение экрана 100 или хотя бы 85 Гц. Спасибо, если кто знает!

Answer (score 1):

> Section "Monitor"
>
> Identifier    "BLABLA"
>
> HorizSync     31-101
>
> VertRefresh    60-101
>
> EndSection

Comment: Ой, забыл, xorg.conf

Comment: Cпасибо за ответ. Ответ есть, а как сделать не знаю???

Comment: Спасибо, объясните кто-нибуть по подробнее